# How to remove the Dash dock from the Application menu? [Ubuntu 22.04]

Tags: dock

I have just Installed The Plank Dock. But when I go to the Activities the old one appears instead. I have tried using the Hide Dash X extension but to no avail, since it says it is unsupported. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

The Ubuntu dock is a gnome shell extension. While you could just turn this extension off in older versions of Ubuntu, this does not work anymore in the default Ubuntu desktop of more recent versions. There are two options.

1. You can remove `gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock`. That will also remove the metapackage for the desktop, `ubuntu-desktop` or `ubuntu-desktop-minimal`, but that will otherwise not remove anything else of the system. Only when upgrading to a newer version, the presence of a meta package makes it more certain that the upgraded desktop is configured as the developers intended.

Probably the better option:

2. You can switch to a default Gnome Shell session instead. Install `ubuntu-gnome-desktop`. This will install an additional Gnome Shell session. All components of the default Ubuntu desktop remain, but a new session will be available that is configured as default Gnome Shell, i.e., without a dock, but with all Ubuntu theming. To switch to that session, click the cog wheel on the bottom right of the login screen before you enter your password. That session will not have the Dock.

   To have a Gnome Session without Ubuntu theming, you can install `vanilla-gnome-desktop` instead.

Comment: Ok, I think I installed it (I'm not that savvy with Ubuntu yet). I typed sudo apt install ubuntu-gnome-desktop in the terminal . So I go to the little cog on the bottom right. And I can select between Gnome, Classic Gnome, Classic gnome on Xorg, Gnome on Xorg, Ubuntu, Ubuntu on Xorg and Unity. Which one of them is it? Also Thanks for the Answer!